# Jackson serializing: Already had POJO for id

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson, entity

I need help. I'm trying to find solution for a long time, I read almost everything there is on the Internet about Jackson JSON serializing and
@JsonIdentityInfo annotations but I can't figure out why I get this error.

I have User (can post multiple requests and can approve multiple requests),
Comment (belongs to one request, posted by one user) and
Request.

I get an error:

```
Could not read document: Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Long) [[ObjectId: key=1, type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator, scope=hr.svgroup.sipa.model.User]] (through reference chain: hr.svgroup.sipa.model.Comment[\"request\"]->hr.svgroup.sipa.model.Request[\"user\"]->hr.svgroup.sipa.model.User[\"id\"]);
```

User class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id",
scope = User.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "approvers")
    private List<Request> approvalRequests;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Request> createdRequests;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Comment> comments;

    ...
}
```

Comment class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id",
    scope = Comment.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "request", nullable = false)
    private Request request;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", nullable = false)
    private User user;  
    ...
}
```

Request class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id",
scope = Request.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
public class Request {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="req_type", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private RequestType requestType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "status", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private RequestStatus status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request")
    private List<Request> comments;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "request_approver", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "request", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<User> approvers;

}
```

I'm using jackson 2.6.5.

Thank You!

Comment: Why are you using `@JsonIdentityInfo` om `Entities` when you can easily get the JSON serialized POJO with `@ResponseBody` or `@ResponseEntity` on `@Controller` methods?

Comment: I get infinite recursion otherwise because of bidirectional relationships.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't notice that.

Comment: This might happen if you have two different instances of your class that have the same id. This would be something that you would have to fix in your code outside of what you have provided.